# Query 1 column in a table based off 2 other columns combined

Tags: sql

Table Test

- RPAN8 Column
- RPVR01 Column

Searching for Unique occurrences of RPAN8 in (PRAN8 + RPVR01).

```
SELECT RPAN8 
FROM Test
WHERE RPAN8 IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(RPVR01, RPAN8)) 
                FROM Test);
```

Comment: SELECT RPAN8 FROM Test T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Test T2 WHERE CONCAT(T2.RPVR01,T2.RPAN8) = T1.RPAN8)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you want values that appear only once.  You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

It is unclear if you want `RPAN8` values that appear only once with their `RPVR01` value:

```
SELECT RPAN8, MAX(RPVR01)
FROM Test
GROUP BY RPAN8
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Or if you want pairs that only appear once:

```
SELECT RPAN8, RPVR01
FROM Test
GROUP BY RPAN8, RPVR01
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```